# After updating flutter sdk 3.1.0 from official website flutter_paystack plugin is not working

Tags: flutter, paystack

C:\flutter sdk\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_paystack-1.0.5+1\android\src\main\kotlin\co\paystack\flutterpaystack\FlutterPaystackPlugin.kt: (25, 62): Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected

C:\flutter sdk\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_paystack-1.0.5+1\android\src\main\kotlin\co\paystack\flutterpaystack\FlutterPaystackPlugin.kt: (36, 28): Type mismatch: inferred type is BinaryMessenger? but BinaryMessenger was expected

Getting above error in flutter_paystack: ^1.0.5

can anyone help me to fix it out ?

Comment: what is your last flutter & dart version?

Comment: Last flutter sdk version was 2.8.0

Comment: for me cancel payment button not working on mobile webview? do you have any solutions for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If package **flutter_paystack: 1.0.5+1** does not work on **flutter 3**

Then try changing dependency of **flutter_paystack 1.0.5+1** in pubspec.yaml to:

```
flutter_paystack:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/definitelyme/flutter_paystack.git
      ref: a4a33c3dd0a12f46d655a2e63d11e9f20ba82d01
```

Comment: YES, It was not supported in flutter 3.0.0 & 3.1.0. but, It is working in flutter sdk 2.10.5. I just used latest version of flutter_paystack. Thank you